# docker-compose : run container continuously

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-blob-storage

I have a computer not compatible with blobfuse2.

In order to tackle the issue, i'd like to mount an azure blob storage throught a container.

I've created 3 files :

> dockerfile.base : Create a base blobfuse compliant image...

```
FROM amd64/ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y wget

# We install Microsoft packages Repository
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && apt update

# We install blobfuse
RUN apt install -y libfuse3-dev fuse3 \
    && apt install -y blobfuse2 tree
```

It is build without problem and i give it the name "blobfuse2".

Then i've created another image that will be specific to the storage account / container i'll want to mount :

> dockerfile.data : mount a storage.

```
FROM blobfuse2:latest
COPY config/ config/
RUN mkdir /tmp/.azcache && mkdir /mnt/azmnt
CMD ["blobfuse2","mount","all","/mnt/azmnt/","--config-file=config/storage_data.yaml","&&","sleep","infinity"]
```

As you can see, i just reuse the original container, inject the configuration file for blobfuse and mount the storage.
I added the command **"sleep infinity"** in the end of the **CMD**, in order to keep the container alive while i need it.

Finally, i've created a docker compose in order to run it :

> docker-compose.yaml : Launch the container in order to see files

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  diffusion_data:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile.data
    privileged: true 
    volumes:
      - /mnt:/mnt/azmnt
```

The expected behavior is that the storage account is available when i launch my docker compose. For example :

```bash
>> docker-compose up
>>ls /mnt/azmt/data
# => returns content of data.
```

The result is that :

```
Starting blobfuse_data_1 ... done
Attaching to blobfuse_data_1
data_1  | Mounting container : data to path  /mnt/azmnt/data
data_1  | 
data_1  | 1 of 1 containers were successfully mounted
blobfuse_data_1 exited with code 0
>> ls /mnt/data 
# => returns nothing
```

It seems that the container exits just after beeing launched like if the "sleep infinity" was ignored.

Do you have any idea aout how to make it work ?
If you have any other idea to mount an azure **blob** storage (no smb or fileshare) without a vnet on an AppleSilicon Mac, it can also be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to write a `CMD` statement: shell and exec. The exec form, that you use, is using the `[]` and has the command encapsulated. As opposed to the shell form, where you "just" put your commands as is.

The exec form is a lot more common these days, mainly because it doesn't spawn sub process in shells, but you also miss out on certain things, most importantly for you: command chaining.

Looking at an example makes this more obvious:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

CMD ["ls", "&&", "sleep", "infinity"]
```

This `CMD`  using the exec form will never execute the second command, but treat it as input for `ls`:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm testy
ls: cannot access '&&': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'sleep': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'infinity': No such file or directory
```

The same but in the shell form:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm testy
bin   dev  home  media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  etc  lib   mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
```

And then it will go on to sleep forever.

Therefore, you need to adjust you `CMD` to the following:

```
CMD blobfuse2 mount all /mnt/azmnt/ --config-file=config/storage_data.yaml && sleep infinity
```